# SQL - Group by in PIVOT with variable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to group my output by date. For each entry in this table, there are order detail lines for each unique style, (N styles), with an order date and shipped quantity. My goal is to have an output with a header of date, styles and the associated order dates and ship totals in each row. Right now, I have a row for each detail line instead of a rollup. I have tried `group by order_date, '+@PivotColumns+'` but that doesn't work. I can't just do `group by order_date` either of course. Do I need to do another query on the result maybe?

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(rtrim(style))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT style FROM opendet where isnumeric(style)=1 and season='ESSENTIALS') AS stylepivot

SET   @SQLQuery = N'
select
order_date,'+@PivotColumns+'
FROM opendet
PIVOT(
 SUM(SHIP_QTY)
 FOR style IN ('+@PivotColumns+')
) AS P'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

This is what I am getting now:

```
order_date  15080   15082   15083   
2012-12-12  1       NULL    NULL
2012-12-13  NULL    1       NULL
2012-12-13  NULL    2       NULL
2012-12-14  NULL    NULL    1
2012-12-14  NULL    NULL    1
2012-12-15  NULL    NULL    NULL
2012-12-16  1       NULL    NULL
2012-12-16  4       NULL    NULL
2012-12-16  3       NULL    NULL
```

This is what I want:

```
order_date  15080   15082   15083   
2012-12-12  1       NULL    NULL
2012-12-13  NULL    3       NULL
2012-12-14  NULL    NULL    2
2012-12-15  NULL    NULL    NULL
2012-12-16  8       NULL    NULL
```

Here is an trimmed excerpt of the source table, (there are many more columns):

```
order_date  style   season      ship_qty
2014-01-06  15082   ESSENTIALS  2.00
2014-01-06  15082   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-06  15082   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-06  15082   ESSENTIALS  2.00
2014-01-08  15080   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-08  15080   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-08  15080   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-08  15080   ESSENTIALS  1.00
2014-01-08  15082   ESSENTIALS  2.00
2014-01-08  15082   ESSENTIALS  2.00
2014-01-08  15082   ESSENTIALS  2.00
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: Done. I debated on adding that in the beginning.

Comment: SQL fiddle would make it easier for others to try and test

Comment: What data type is your `order_date` field?

Comment: Also, don't forget to order `styles` in `@PivotColumns` building query if you don't want its corresponding columns mixed in final report table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to pre-aggregate to the style/date level before the pivot:

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT   @PivotColumns= COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(rtrim(style))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT style FROM opendet where isnumeric(style)=1 and season='ESSENTIALS') AS stylepivot

SET   @SQLQuery = N'
select
order_date,'+@PivotColumns+'
FROM (SELECT order_date,style, SUM(Ship_Qty) AS Ship_Qty
      FROM opendet
      GROUP BY order_date,style
      )sub
PIVOT(
 SUM(SHIP_QTY)
 FOR style IN ('+@PivotColumns+')
) AS P'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```